# pgfplots - Add offset to pins

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, nodes

I'm trying to make a bar plot for an optimization parameter in quantum physics. To be more informative, the graph should display the values of these parameters above the bars. So far I did

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$E_0$ über $n$}, ymax=2.5, yticklabels=]
      \addplot [blue!90!white, fill=blue!50!white, ybar] coordinates {
        ( 1, 1.96556 )
        ( 2, 1.86105 )
        ( 3, 1.93185 )
        ( 4, 2.02568 )
        ( 5, 2.12077 )
        ( 6, 2.21219 )
      };
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in {1/1.96556, 2/1.86105, 3/1.93185, 4/2.02568, 5/2.12077, 6/2.21219} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate, pin={[rotate=90]0:\y}] at (axis cs:\x,\y) {};}\temp
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This code outputs the following graph

> [image: Optimization for a particle in the gravitational field]

Now I tried to add a little space between the bars and the pins, but I failed. I tried `++ (axis cs:0,0.1)`

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate, pin={[rotate=90]0:\y}] at (axis cs:\x,\y) ++ (axis cs:0,0.1) {};}\temp
```

and `++ (axis direction cs:0,0.1)`

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate, pin={[rotate=90]0:\y}] at (axis cs:\x,\y) ++ (axis direction cs:0,0.1) {};}\temp
```

Both variants give this error:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
```

I also tried `pos=0.1`

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate, pin={[rotate=90]0:\y},pos=0.1] at (axis cs:\x,\y) {};}\temp
```

which compiles fine but gives this output

> [image: Broken version of the upper graph]

Thanks in advance, maeru.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I added a MWE now. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @maeru: Instead of editing the question to include the solution you went with, you should post an answer yourself. That keeps the site more organised.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would stick to the `pgfplots` as much as I can for the node style. You can pass pin options to the `nodes near coords` and also many other options (colors, linestyles etc.) as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={$E_0$ über $n$}, ymax=2.5, yticklabels=,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=4]\pgfplotspointmeta},
nodes near coords align={
     shift={(0,1.5cm)},
     rotate=90,
     pin={[pin distance = 0.75cm,
          pin edge={thick,double=yellow}]180:},
     text=red
}
]
  \addplot [blue!90!white, fill=blue!50!white, ybar] coordinates {
    ( 1, 1.96556 )
    ( 2, 1.86105 )
    ( 3, 1.93185 )
    ( 4, 2.02568 )
    ( 5, 2.12077 )
    ( 6, 2.21219 )
  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Excellent answer! I couldn't figure out how to make the pin line go straight up with the rotated text. Doing it the other way round (with an empty pin) is a great idea

Comment: Can I adjust the precision of the labels and/or control their color?

Comment: @maeru Ah I forgot that completely. Sorry. I'll edit this in a minute.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do hat is to use tikz's `calc` library to adjust the coordinate of where the pin is being placed:

```
($(axis cs:\x,\y)+(0.0cm,0.1cm)$)
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$E_0$ über $n$}, ymax=2.5, yticklabels=]
      \addplot [blue!90!white, fill=blue!50!white, ybar] coordinates {
        ( 1, 1.96556 )
        ( 2, 1.86105 )
        ( 3, 1.93185 )
        ( 4, 2.02568 )
        ( 5, 2.12077 )
        ( 6, 2.21219 )
      };
      \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in {1/1.96556, 2/1.86105, 3/1.93185, 4/2.02568, 5/2.12077, 6/2.21219} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate, pin={[rotate=90]0:\y}] at ($(axis cs:\x,\y)+(0.0cm,0.1cm)$) {};}\temp
      }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**My solution**

There are great answers to this, but I took the path of least resistance and just added `shift={(0,0.1cm)}`

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\node[coordinate,shift={(0,0.1cm)},pin = {[rotate=90]0:\y}] at (axis cs:\x,\y) { };}
```