# Help with grouped bar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to recreate the graph below but I am unsure how I could add another y-axis as the two series have different units. 
[![Graph][1]][1]

Right now I have only added the data for value (return and Sharpe ratio) and I am unsure how to continue. I got the graph below by starting with the example from [grouped bar chart with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152143/grouped-bar-chart-with-pgfplots) and editing some things to my need. Hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    },
    every node near coord/.style={
        /pgfplots/calculate offset,
        yshift=-\testmacro
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
  %Value-return    %Growth
0 6.4              4.5      
1 12.8             4.4      
2 13.6             6.5      
3 11.1             9.4      
}\dataset
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
        width=12cm,
        height=8cm,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=16,        
        ylabel={Average annual return (\%)},
        xtick=data,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        xticklabels = {
            P/E ratio,
            P/B ratio,
            P/C ratio,
            P/S ratio
        },
        xticklabel style={yshift=-10ex},
        major x tick style = {opacity=0},
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor tick length=2ex,
        area legend,
        every node near coord/.append style={
                anchor=east,
                rotate=90
        }
        ]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!20] table[x index=0,y index=1] \dataset; %Return
\addlegendentry{Return}
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset; %Sharpe ratio
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=plain, labelformat=default}
\caption{Average annual returns and Sharpe ratios for value and growth portfolios in the period 1992-2017, portfolios were created using different financial ratios.}
\label{fig:overview}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** With some help I have made some steps, now I almost have it how I want it. [image: Link] 
The picture above is what I have right now. I would like to hide the small lines above value and growth and if possible move the title up a little bit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{caption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\BarOffset}{0.15}

    \pgfplotsset{
    % define a new style to use on both axis environments
    MyAxis/.style={
            ybar,
            scale only axis,
            width=12cm,
            height=8cm,
            ymin=0,
            xmin=-0.5,
            xmax=7.5, % you need to increase this if you add more data
            area legend,
            bar width=10pt
      }
    }

    \pgfplotstableread{
      %Returns         %Sharpe
    0 6.4              0.232      
    1 4.5              0.279      
    2 12.8             0.397      
    3 4.4              0.279   
    4 13.6             0.462
    5 6.5              0.221
    6 11.1             0.337
    7 9.4              0.377

    }\dataset

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title= \Large{Average annual returns and Sharpe ratios for value and growth portfolios},
        ylabel={Average annual return (\%)},
        ymax=16,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xtick={0,...,7},
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        xticklabels = {
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth
        },
        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
        tickwidth=5pt,
        extra x ticks={-0.5,1.5,...,3.5,5.5,7.5},
        extra x tick labels={},
        extra x tick style={tickwidth=1.2cm},
        minor x tick style = {opacity=0},
        MyAxis
    ]
    \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!20] table[x expr=\coordindex-\BarOffset,y index=1] \dataset; %Return
    \label{returnplot}
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        name=ax2,
        ymax=0.5,
        MyAxis,
        ylabel=Average Sharpe ratio,
        ytick pos=right,
        yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex},
        clip=false,
        xtick={0.5,2.5,4.5,6.5},
        xticklabels={P/E ratio, P/B ratio, P/C ratio, P/S ratio},
        xticklabel style={yshift=-5mm},
        tickwidth=5pt,
        xtick style={draw=none}
    ]
    \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40] table[x expr=\coordindex+\BarOffset,y index=2] \dataset; %Sharpe ratio
    \label{ratioplot}

    \end{axis}

    % legend
    \node [below=1.3cm] at (ax2.south) {\ref{returnplot} Return \quad \ref{ratioplot} Sharpe ratio};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=plain, labelformat=default}
    \caption{Average annual returns and Sharpe ratios for value and growth portfolios in the period 1992-2017, portfolios were created using different financial ratios.}
    \label{fig:overview}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200475/i-have-3-data-series-and-2-different-y-axis-how-can-i-add-outside-the-graph-t) could help?

Comment: @Moriambar Have been trying all sorts of things but am still not able to figure it out. I got [this](https://i.imgur.com/34x3owU.png) I don't know how to move the y label for the second axis to the right axis. Next to that, the two series are overlapping right now.

Comment: @Moriambar I have gotten a little bit further, [this](https://i.imgur.com/wOQ3jMR.png) is what it looks like now. I want to move the y-label to the right axis and center the of the ratio under value and growth.

Comment: Unfortunately I messed around for a solid 20minutes with this code to no avail. Please update your example with your new result; perhaps someone more expert than me could help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. There isn't  much explanations here, but ask if there is anything that is unclear.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{caption}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\BarOffset}{0.15}

    \pgfplotsset{
    % define a new style to use on both axis environments
    MyAxis/.style={
            ybar,
            scale only axis,
            width=12cm,
            height=8cm,
            ymin=0,
            xmin=-0.5,
            xmax=7.5, % you need to increase this if you add more data
            area legend,
            bar width=10pt
      }
    }

    \pgfplotstableread{
      %Returns         %Sharpe
    0 6.4              0.232      
    1 4.5              0.279      
    2 12.8             0.397      
    3 4.4              0.279   
    4 13.6             0.462
    5 6.5              0.221
    6 11.1             0.337
    7 9.4              0.377

    }\dataset

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title= {Average annual returns and\\Sharpe ratios for value and growth portfolios}, %% modified
        title style={yshift=3mm,font=\Large,align=center}, % added
        ylabel={Average annual return (\%)},
        ymax=16,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xtick={0,...,7},
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        xticklabels = {
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth,
           Value,
           Growth
        },
        yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
        xticklabel style={yshift=-5pt}, %% added
        tickwidth=0pt, % modified
        extra x ticks={-0.5,1.5,...,3.5,5.5,7.5},
        extra x tick labels={},
        extra x tick style={tickwidth=1.2cm},
        minor x tick style = {opacity=0},
        MyAxis
    ]
    \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!20] table[x expr=\coordindex-\BarOffset,y index=1] \dataset; %Return
    \label{returnplot}
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
        name=ax2,
        ymax=0.5,
        MyAxis,
        ylabel=Average Sharpe ratio,
        ytick pos=right,
        yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex},
        clip=false,
        xtick={0.5,2.5,4.5,6.5},
        xticklabels={P/E ratio, P/B ratio, P/C ratio, P/S ratio},
        xticklabel style={yshift=-5mm},
        tickwidth=5pt,
        xtick style={draw=none}
    ]
    \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40] table[x expr=\coordindex+\BarOffset,y index=2] \dataset; %Sharpe ratio
    \label{ratioplot}

    \end{axis}

    % legend
    \node [below=1.3cm] at (ax2.south) {\ref{returnplot} Return \quad \ref{ratioplot} Sharpe ratio};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=plain, labelformat=default}
    \caption{Average annual returns and Sharpe ratios for value and growth portfolios in the period 1992-2017, portfolios were created using different financial ratios.}
    \label{fig:overview}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I almost got it figured out, you helped me out a lot. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwP9v.png) is what I have right now. I would like to hide the small lines above value and growth and if possible move the title up a little bit. I've updated my post with the source.

Comment: @jlatta See edited answer, I added some comments where I added or modified things, all in the first `axis` environment. The line break in the title is because it caused an overfull hbox (the title was 19pt wider than the textblock).